# Getting error when archiving in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting this error while trying to archive the Android Project:

```
XA3001: Could not AOT the assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll
Done building project "App.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
```

The build configuration is as follows:

[Build Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMegR.jpg)

Comment: If you disable the AOT Compilation,could it archive succesfully ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes, it does archive successfully when AOT is disabled.

Comment: same issue here - only works with AOT disabled

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue and spent many hours trying to solve it. It occurred after I updated my Xamarin project to use the new AndroidX libraries. I had some packages installed that were no longer required. I managed to resolve it by removing the AndroidX packages one at a time and then running my application in debug mode to see if the package was really needed. Thereafter I tested in release with AOT enabled and it worked.

After some more digging, I found the offending package was `Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter` so I suggest starting with that.

Comment: I had this package installed as part of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Cast package I was using with firebase. I removed the package, but the problem persisted. I tried to remove the package manually in the console and it doens't exist, so I'm sure its gone. I had to disable AOT to get it to build. In the Android options menu, I unticked Enable Startup Tracing. Apparently startup tracing is AOT?

Comment: @pseudoabdul No. Startup tracing != AOT, although start-up tracing can be used together with AOT. You can find out more here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/faster-startup-times-with-startup-tracing-on-android/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Disabling startup tracing did resolve all my AOT problems tho

Answer (score 1):

After the comment of @pseudoabdul I have tried disabling "Startup Tracing" and this solved solved the issue with "Could not AOT the assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll".

Answer (score 0):

Just a recommendation, but the link you refer to above is now very old. You should really be referring to https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/OneDotNet.md for the latest recommendations. Admittedly the docs I'm referring to are about Net6, Net7 etc. but they explain indirectly all the correct recommendations for Xamarin.Android projects as well. Your projects must have other problems if ProfiledAot is not working for you and you certainly don't want to turn it off because it drastically improves start-up time. Another easier way would be just convert your project to Net7 now. You have to for Android 14 which is now only weeks away.